# Media Queries in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have to implement some media queries into my code & use col's.

I've managed to fix most of it, however when it comes to my tablet solution I can't figure out what to do.

The thing is, the col-4 & col-8 is supposed to be for tablet, and in the product box the picture is supposed to be on the right, and the text on the left (all inside the box).

This is my HTML code first, and then CSS bottom.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>ZENFERIER.NO</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/meyersReset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">     
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <!-- Header område, inkluderer header, banner og nav -->
        <header id="mainPageHeader"> <a id="logo" href="#ng">Zenferier.no</a>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#ng">Hjem</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#ng">Om Oss</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#ng">Reisetips</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#ng">Kontakt Oss</a> </li>
            </ul>

            <div id="mainPageBanner" class="img-responsive">
                <div id="tekstBanner">Book din ferie hos oss!</div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <!-- slutt header område -->

        <!-- hovedområde med produktbokser -->
        <main id="mainContent">

            <article class="product-box col-screen1-4 col-screen1-5 col-tablet-4 col-tablet-8">
                <div class="product-content-box"> <img src="img/tenerife.jpg" alt="Bilde Tenerife" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                   <div class="product-content-box">
                    <h2>Tenerife</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam quidem enim accusamus necessitatibus placeat repellendus iusto, ex doloremque culpa libero architecto neque recusandae quaerat dicta sit amet. Maiores, officia, excepturi.</p>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="product-box col-screen1-4 col-screen1-5 col-tablet-4 col-tablet-8">
                <div class="product-content-box"> <img src="img/kyoto.jpg" alt="Bilde Kyoto" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                <div class="product-content-box">
                    <h2>Kyoto</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam quidem enim accusamus necessitatibus placeat repellendus iusto, ex doloremque culpa libero architecto neque recusandae quaerat dicta sit amet. Maiores, officia, excepturi.</p>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="product-box col-screen1-4 col-screen1-5 col-tablet-4 col-tablet-8">
                <div class="product-content-box"> <img src="img/barcelona.jpg" alt="Bilde Barcelona" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                <div class="product-content-box">
                    <h2>Barcelona</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam quidem enim accusamus necessitatibus placeat repellendus iusto, ex doloremque culpa libero architecto neque recusandae quaerat dicta sit amet. Maiores, officia, excepturi.</p>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="product-box col-screen1-4 col-screen1-5 col-tablet-4 col-tablet-8">
                <div class="product-content-box"> <img src="img/lasvegas.jpg" alt="Bilde Las Vegas" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                <div class="product-content-box">
                    <h2>Las Vegas</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam quidem enim accusamus necessitatibus placeat repellendus iusto, ex doloremque culpa libero architecto neque recusandae quaerat dicta sit amet. Maiores, officia, excepturi.</p>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="product-box col-screen1-4 col-screen1-5 col-tablet-4 col-tablet-8">
                <div class="product-content-box"> <img src="img/london.jpg" alt="Bilde London" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                <div class="product-content-box">
                    <h2>London</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam quidem enim accusamus necessitatibus placeat repellendus iusto, ex doloremque culpa libero architecto neque recusandae quaerat dicta sit amet. Maiores, officia, excepturi.</p>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="product-box col-screen1-4 col-screen1-5 col-tablet-4 col-tablet-8">
                <div class="product-content-box"> <img src="img/tokyo.jpg" alt="Bilde Tokyo" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                <div class="product-content-box">
                    <h2>Tokyo</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam quidem enim accusamus necessitatibus placeat repellendus iusto, ex doloremque culpa libero architecto neque recusandae quaerat dicta sit amet. Maiores, officia, excepturi.</p>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="product-box col-screen1-4 col-screen1-5 col-tablet-4 col-tablet-8">
                <div class="product-content-box"> <img src="img/paris.jpg" alt="Bilde Paris" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                <div class="product-content-box">
                    <h2>Paris</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam quidem enim accusamus necessitatibus placeat repellendus iusto, ex doloremque culpa libero architecto neque recusandae quaerat dicta sit amet. Maiores, officia, excepturi.</p>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="product-box col-screen1-4 col-screen1-5 col-tablet-4 col-tablet-8">
                <div class="product-content-box"> <img src="img/berlin.jpg" alt="Bilde Berlin" class="img-responsive"> </div>
                <div class="product-content-box">
                    <h2>Berlin</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam quidem enim accusamus necessitatibus placeat repellendus iusto, ex doloremque culpa libero architecto neque recusandae quaerat dicta sit amet. Maiores, officia, excepturi.</p>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class="product-box col-screen1-4 col-screen1-5 col-tablet-4 col-tablet-8">
                <div class="product-content-box"> <img src="img/oslo.jpg" alt="Bilde Oslo" class="img-responsive"></div>
                <div class="product-content-box">
                    <h2>Oslo</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam quidem enim accusamus necessitatibus placeat repellendus iusto, ex doloremque culpa libero architecto neque recusandae quaerat dicta sit amet. Maiores, officia, excepturi.</p>
                </div>
            </article>

        </main>
        <!-- slutt hovedområde -->

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
body {
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    max-width: 80%;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}


/*-- mainPageHeader --*/

#mainPageHeader {
    background-color: #797067;
    max-width: 100%;
}

#logo {
    color: #FFFDF6;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 0.25em;
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
}


/*-- end mainPageHeader --*/


/*-- mainPageNav --*/

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #4D8FAB;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: #FFFDF6;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #C4B197;
}


/*-- mainPageBanner --*/

#mainPageBanner {
    height: 250px;
    background-color: #4D8FAB;
    /*blå*/
    background-image: url(../img/banner1.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    display: none;
}


/*-- end mainPageBanner --*/


/*-- tekst på banner --*/

#tekstBanner {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    background-color: #EBDBAE;
    color: #4D8FAB;
    width: 35%;
    height: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 90px;
    display: inline-block;
}


/*-- mainPageFooter --*/

#mainPageFooter {
    background-color: #797067;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
}


/*-- diverse kode --*/

.img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
}

.product-box {
    margin-left: 0.25em;
    margin-right: 0.25em;
}

#mainContent {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size: 30px;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: black;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


/*-- media query tablet --*/

@media screen and (min-width:768px){
    .product-box {
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .product-content-box {
        background-color: #C4B197;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    .col-tablet-4 {
        width: 33,33;
        float: left;
    }

    .col-tablet-8 {
        width: 66,66%;
        float: left;
    }
}
/*-- end media query tablet --*/


/*-- media query screen 1024++ --*/

@media screen and (min-width:1024px){
    .col-screen1-4 {
        width: 33.33%;
    }
    #mainPageBanner {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1240px){
    .col-screen1-5 {
        width: 25%;
    }
    #mainPageBanner {
        display: block;
    }
}


/*-- end media query screen 1024++ --*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the order of the media queries. Put the tablet one below the screen one. It may be overriding it. I hope that helps. :-).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it didnt work. I still cant manage to make the tablet products boxes to end up next to each other :/  its supposed to be like this:
square 1: img -  text     square 2: text img
square 3: text - img      square 4 : img text

Answer (score 0):

I believe you must use the `.` as the decimal separator in CSS - for the first media query, you've set the width for `.col-tablet-4` and `.col-tablet-8` using a comma `,` as the decimal separator. You have also omitted the `%` on the width of `.col-tablet-4`.

Comment: thanks for the . tip! I noticed it right now, i added the % too, but they didnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

replace the media query

- @media screen and (min-width:768px){}

to

- @media screen and (max-width:768px){}